# JavaScript - specific queried from two databases

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need help with a JavaScript task.
How do I get something specific queried from two databases?

Task:
View the index.js file
Implement the gradeOverview() function, which gets the variables students and
grades and creates a grade overview for each student. Thereby
each element in the students array should be projected to an object in the following format:
{ student: (students[i]), grades: [(grades[j], grades[j+k], ...)] }

This is my function which accesses both databases and should retrieve and display a value from one database at a time based on the "student number".

```
    function gradeOverview(students, grades) {
      const result = students.map((student) => [
        {
          student: student,
          grade: grades.reduce((grades, grade) => {
            const student number = grade.studentnumber;
            if (grades[matriculationnumber] == null) grades[matriculationnumber] = [];
            grades[matriculationnumber].push(grade);
            return grades;
          }),
        },
      ]);

  console.log(result);

  return result;

  // TODO: implement me
}
```

The Data:

```
var students = [{
        "matrikelnummer": 4636,
        "vorname": "Vérane",
        "nachname": "Voase"
    }]

var grades = [{
            "id": 628,
            "matrikelnummer": 4636,
            "grade": "3,3"

        },
        {
            "id": 886,
            "matrikelnummer": 4636,
            "grade": "5,0"
        }]
```

Output:

```
"student": {
            "matrikelnummer": 4636,
            "vorname": "Vérane",
            "nachname": "Voase"
        },
        "grades": [
            {
                "id": 628,
                "matrikelnummer": 4636,
                "grade": "3,3"
            },
            {
                "id": 886,
                "matrikelnummer": 4636
                "grade": "3,6"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Fiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/uzrodex3/

I hope i guessed correctly your incoming data you put into gradeOverview function.

```
const studentsQueryResponse = [
    {
        name: "John Doe",
        studentNumber: 123
    },
    {
        name: "Johan Doe",
        studentNumber: 321
    },
    {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        studentNumber: 111
    }
]
```

```
const gradesQueryResponse = [
    {
        studentNumber: 123,
        grade: 1
    },
    {
        studentNumber: 123,
        grade: 3
    },
    {
        studentNumber: 321,
        grade: 5
    },
    {
        studentNumber: 123,
        grade: 1
    }
]
```

There is your function which returns in this case

```
[
   {
      "student": {
         "name":"John Doe",
         "studentNumber":123
      },
      "grade":[1,3,1]
   },
   {  
      "student": {
         "name":"Johan Doe",
         "studentNumber":321
      },
      "grade":[5]
   },
   {
      "student": {
         "name":"Jane Doe",
         "studentNumber":111
      },
      "grade":[]
   }
]
```

**If you want to return whole `grade` object in array, then just remove `map` line which returns grade property value from grade object**

```
function gradeOverview(students, grades) {
    console.log("Input arguments", students, grades)

    const results = students.map((student) => {

        return {
            student: student,
            grade: grades
                .filter((gradeObject) => gradeObject.studentNumber === student.studentNumber)
                .map((gradeObject) => gradeObject.grade)
        }
    });


    console.log("Results", results);
    
    return results;
}
```

And then you call your function

```
gradeOverview(studenstQueryResponse, gradesQueryResponse)
```

Comment: + comment to your code:

1. variable "matriculationnumber" does not exist in context and I guess it should be "studentnumber"
2. there is how Array.reduce works [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

You could use Array.reduce instead of Array.filter but this approach seems to me more readable

Comment: There is code which will work for your updated data.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uzrodex3/)